# Cluster on Demand ie Cluster for Rent

Tags: linux, hosting, selinux

By Cluster on Demand I mean renting a cluster for a specific job.We have a client that requires use of a cluster computer now,while his cluster is being built.
Does anyone out there know what the price to rent a cluster by the core and if they require a minimal period of time. I have seen everything from .50 to $3.00 per core. The use will be for fire simulation using FDS for at least 20 hours. The cluster need of at least 256 cores.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using [amazon's cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) computing service